# Display a Tooltip at Mouse Cursor (via Applescript or Shell Script)?

Tags: macos, applescript, bash

I tried googling for info about this for a while, but came up empty handed.

Is there any way, either with shell or Apple script, or maybe even via python, to display a tooltip relative to the mouse pointer (when using Finder.app)?

Comment: For your own application, sure.

Comment: Apps which have tooltips follow Apple programming APIs and the developers include the tooltip framework in the apps themselves. It is not a native feature that all Apple apps have tooltips by default, if that is what you are trying to accomplish.  You can read the [documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/3750832-tooltip) if you are developing software for macOS, iOS or iPadOS and want to include tooltips.

Comment: @IconDaemon Is there a way to show a tooltip in Finder? That's the main app I'm trying to work with here (updated the question to specify this).

Comment: Apple would have to have the tooltip framework already built into Finder to accomplish this. You may be out of luck on this one.

Comment: @IconDaemon darn... maybe there's a Finder alternative I could use instead, or some way to do it through Keyboard Maestro? Lmk if you know of a viable solution for either. If not, I guess this question is dead. 